# How to iterate on json fields and insert new values using json4s?

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a simple json file:

```
  val myJson =  {
      "field1": [
        {
          "name": "john",
          "lname": "knight"
        },
        {
          "name": "jack",
          "lname": "samuel"
        },
        {
          "name": "elinor",
          "lname": "cooper"
        }
      ],
      "field2": [
        {
          ...
        },
        {
          ...
        },
        {
          ...
        }
      ],
      "field3": [
        {
          ...
        },
        {
          ...
        },
        {
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
```

and what i want is to be able to iterate on "field1" and for each name to call a method that returns some value and insert this value to the json under "fiel1".

// this returns a list of strings

```
val kids = getKids("john")
```

// this is will me the returned value

```
kids = List("amy", "tom")
```

now I want to insert it:

```
{
  "field1": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "lname": "knight"
      "kids": ["amy", "tom"]
    },
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "lname": "samuel"
      "kids": ["edi", "keren"]
    },
    {
      "name": "elinor",
      "lname": "cooper"
      "kids": ["lilly", "mag"]
    }
  ]
...
```

but I want to iterate on all the names and do this for each one...how can I accomplish this with json4s?

so lets say i have the parsed json:

val myParsedJson = JsonMethods.parse(myJson)

how do I go from here?

thanks!

Comment: I've always found it easier to convert json to case classes, and then regenerate from there - would that be an option here?

Comment: @Reactormonk its kind of plan b for me :) since the json is kinda big so didnt want to do that, but If I wont be able to find a simple enough solution I would go with this path...